# Corruption of heap at FileOutputStream object in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, filestream, heap-corruption

In my sample program I get "corruption of heap" error at the following line.

```
ofstream filePossibleHaplotype;
```

"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Project_Name.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Project_Name.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded."

How does declaration of a file stream object cause this error ?

[EDIT - Added few snippets of code]
SET = 1
NOT_SET = 0
LENGTH = 5

```
void fill_Unique_Bit_Array()
    {
        int zeroFlag = NOT_SET;
        int oneFlag = NOT_SET;
        bit_array = new int(LENGTH);
        for(int i =0; i<LENGTH; i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; j<NUMBER_OF_READS; j++)
            {
                if(readMartixArray[j][i] == '0')
                    zeroFlag = SET;
                else if (readMartixArray[j][i] == '1')
                    oneFlag = SET;
            }
            if(zeroFlag==SET && oneFlag==SET)
                bit_array[i] = SET + SET;
            else if(zeroFlag==SET && oneFlag==NOT_SET)
                bit_array[i] = NOT_SET;
            else if(zeroFlag==NOT_SET && oneFlag==SET)
                bit_array[i] = SET;
            zeroFlag = NOT_SET;
            oneFlag = NOT_SET;
        }
        reverse_bit_array = array_Reverse(bit_array, LENGTH);        
    }
```

This function calls,

```
void find_all_possible_combinations(int ,int, int, int )
    {
        ofstream filePossibleHaplotype;
    }
```

which leads to crash of heap memory.

Comment: Infinite recursion? There is also the possibility the line of code is a victim of corruption that occurred earlier in your program, if `ofstream` is using the heap in its constructor.

Comment: Please post more code for context.  That particular line is almost certainly not the culprit.

Comment: Are you sure it's not actually happening at the line above that one? The yellow arrow in the debugger shows the _next_ line to be executed.

Comment: This piece of code is at the start of the function where am getting the crash. So does it have anything to do with the previously called function?

Comment: I am using couple of dynamic memory allocation but of very small size and performing matrix operations along with file read write operations.

Comment: Show the function declaration too, and how it is being called.

Comment: You most likely write outside the boundaries of an array somewhere. Check all your array and matrix code, to make sure things like e.g. loop conditions doesn't contain `i <= SIZE`. One way to make sure is to step through all the code in the debugger, checking all indexes and variables. Sure it can take a lot of time, but you will most likely find the problem.

Comment: Is `find_all_possible_combinations` recursive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with dynamic memory allocation of bit_array. I created a normal static array and the code worked fine. But I am not sure of why the dynamic array allocation is causing an issue.I  have declared the int pointer as a global variable.

bit_array = new int(LENGTH);